# A bookmarklet to scroll to the bottom of a webpage

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

i wonder if it is possible to create a bookmarklet to click on and the current webpage scrolls to the bottom!

```
javascript:function%20scrollme(){dh=document.body.scrollHeight;ch=document.body.clientHeight;if(dh>ch){moveme=dh-ch;window.scrollTo(0,moveme);}}
```

if i create a new bookmark and paste this as address nothing happens. I actually have no idea how to run javascript within a bookmarklet, however i just bookmarked the css-tricks [Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/)

maybe you could help, i would love to have a bookmarklet like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your JavaScript only defines a function and does nothing else.

Second, you need to use `document.documentElement` (which represents the `<html>` element) instead of `document.body`:

```
javascript:dh=document.documentElement.scrollHeight;ch=document.documentElement.clientHeight;if(dh>ch){moveme=dh-ch;window.scrollTo(0,moveme);}
```

or, simply

```
javascript:window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
```

(apparently it doesn't matter if `y-coord` of [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) is greater than the maximum position).

*Update:* In case you have to deal with IE in quirks mode, the root element is indeed `document.body`. Other browsers let `document.documentElement.clientHeight` represent the document's height (see [Finding the size of the browser window](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow), which deals with the window's height, but contains a nice table). Anyway, you want to set the position of the scroller to whatever is the greatest of the three:

```
javascript:window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that smoothly scrolls down to the bottom of a page:

```
function scroll(scroll_to) {
if (scroll.timer) clearTimeout(scroll.timer);
var scroll_current = document.body.scrollTop,
    distance = Math.abs(scroll_current - scroll_to);
if (scroll_current == scroll_to) return;
if (scroll_current > scroll_to) {
    if (distance < 5) {
        scroll_current -= distance;
    } else {
        scroll_current -= Math.ceil(distance / 10);
    }
}
if (scroll_current < scroll_to) {
    if (distance < 5) {
        scroll_current += distance;
    } else {
        scroll_current += Math.ceil(distance / 10);
    }
}
document.body.scrollTop = scroll_current;
scroll.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    scroll(scroll_to)
    }, 10);
}
```

If you call it:

```
scroll(document.body.scrollHeight - innerHeight);
```

it will scroll to the bottom of the page.
You can also use it to scroll to the top of the page like this:

```
scroll(0);
```

Just attach it to a button or link's `onclick` event.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use an anchor with this syntax

```
<a name="label">Any content</a> 
and
<a href="#label">Any content</a>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the original poster wants.  He wants a bookmarklet that will jump to the body of any page.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a JS solution if it will be used as a bookmarklet; he won't have control over the webpage.

Comment: right, i want a bookmarklet so i can jump to the bottom of every webpage! i can't place an anchor inside of website i visit. i just want to click a bookmarklet and jump to the bottom of the page.